# An entire function with a bound on its integral is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $\int_0^{2\pi} |f(r e^{it})| dt\leq r^{\frac{41}{3}}$ for all $r>0$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

I thought of using Liouville's theorem, combined with Cauchy's estimates. To do so, I tried to use Cauchy's integral formula, but it is not possible to bound the term $|w-z|$ which appears below in the integral.

Anyone can give me a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\gamma$ as the circle of radius $r$ around the origin. Cauchy's Integral Formula gives us

$$
|f^{(n)}(0)| = \frac{n!}{2\pi} \left|\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi^{n+1}}d \xi \right|
\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{|f(re^{it})|}{|r|^{n}}dt.
$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: Ahh, this is the way to prove Cauchy's estimate. I didn't think of it. Well, thank you! Using the bound, by taking $r\to\infty$ and $r\to 0$ I'll get the result I think.

Comment: Yep, take $r$ to both of those values for the conclusion. I am sure there are many, many ways to do this problem, including Liouville's Theorem, but this is the most immediate one to me.