# Proving an Entire Function is 0

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following prelim question:

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function satisfying
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|dt \leq r^{13/4}$$
for all $r>0$. Show that $f \equiv 0$.

It looks like there are two parts to the solution. The first might be to show that $f$ is bounded implying it is constant via Liouville's Theorem. The second part to the solution would show that $f$ is zero at some point, probably $0$. Maybe multiple applications of the Cauchy Inequalities could show this, or a good use of the ML-Inequality, but I have yet to find the correct application. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3494605/42969 for a *very* similar problem.

Comment: That solves my problem. Thanks a lot.